# FbUnityInterface.mm - Lexical or Preprocessor issue

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

In the last two facebook sdk updates (4.2.1, 4.2.4), i get the error specified in the title. I just slap in this at the top of the file:

```
#define USE_NEW_APP_CLASS_NAME 1
```

and it seems to fix it and run fine. Just wondering if there is some other way this is supposed to be getting addressed... using unity 4.2

Comment: That line should have been put in RegisterMonoModules.h as a post build step.  Can you take a look in yours and see if it's there?

Comment: Hmm, not in there. Also, tried to do a store submission earlier, and i get this error:

_The app references non-public selectors in Payload/AppName.app/AppName: id, setId:_

This project is a copy of another, and the only difference is Unity4.2 vs 3.5.6 and FB SDK vs Prime31 FB Plugin. So not sure which is the culprit, ripping out FB SDK now to see if that's it, and if it is, would be bad mojo as apple will likely reject submission with this warning...

Comment: Verified, took out the Facebook SDK and now app verification doesn't give me the 'referencing non-public selector' warning. This is a pretty big problem I would think...

Comment: Here's the answer to your non public function problem, still looking into the other http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053569/facebook-unity-sdk-using-non-public-api-on-ios/19060264#19060264