# Facebook Unity SDK using non-public api on iOS?

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

I tried doing an iTunes submission of our first game using the facebook sdk, and i get this warning:

> The app references non-public selectors in
>   Payload/AppName.app/AppName: id, setId:

I have confirmed that ripping out the Facebook SDK removes this error on submission. Unfortunately, this kind of error usually results in rejection by Apple. Anybody submit successfully with this warning?

Can this be fixed by Facebook to prevent the warning?

Comment: I have the same warning and i'll ignore it, i'm submitting right now !

Answer (score 2):

We just put up a version that fixes this problem.  You can grab it here: http://beta-fb-unity-sdks.parseapp.com/v4.2.5/FacebookSDK.unitypackage

Comment: Klaus: this also has our first pass at compiling resources in at the top level using Unity's new .project support, if you're still having the resource conflict problem, and this fixes it, please let us know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Having issues importing and building this in my project (unity complains about bad folders called drawable.meta), but I pulled this plugin plus the offending one into an empty project, and they seemed to behave with one another better. Also, the private api thing is fixed and our game submitted without warnings. Now just waiting on the urlSchemaSuffix addition to Login, and we should be in the clear... Thanks!